# install python module for particular python instance

Tags: centos, yum, python

I have 2 python instance on a CentOS machine, i.e. `/usr/bin/python2.4` and `/usr/bin/python2.7`.

Modules for 2.4 are in `/usr/lib/python2.4`, and modules for 2.7 are in `/usr/local/python27`.

When I do `yum install numpy`, which I want to install for `python2.7`, it automatically install for `python2.4`.

How can I appoint which instance to install modules for with `yum`, `easy_install` and `pip`?

Answer (score 3):

Your `yum` probably only has packages for the Python version that is used by the OS (it is possible to share, package-manager installed, native python modules between different versions but it is more difficult to configure).

The best option for you is install pip for your `/usr/local/python27` by downloading [`get-pip.py` as per the manual](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html) and then running it with the python2.7 executable:

```
python2.7 get-pip.py
```

You only have to this once, and this will give you a command `pip2.7` which you can use to install any package from PyPI into the Python 2.7 setup.